# Arduino Interrupts and simultaneous activity

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

I have some code that does multiple things and I would like some information pertaining to the various kinds of interrupts. Most of my code is event based. So I am using timers to call certain events. However, when some of the events occur, a relay that I have configured for a different event ends up going on and off for a brief period.

For example, a piece of code goes to the internet and reads the status of a text file in a folder in my server.  If the value is 0 the relay is off, if the value is 1, the relay is on. Currently, I am polling every 30 seconds in order to read a change on the file. I have php script that allows me to write to that text file.  Meanwhile, I have another event that sends data to the web every hour. When I send the data, a brief moment the status of the relay goes on or off depending on the initial state before the data is sent.

Its kinda annoying, since I know that relay should stay on or off when I know that text file didn’t change its state, because I didn’t write to it. So the other event somehow causes the relay to turn on or off without me telling it to. How is this so? Would interrupts work? Internal, external? I still want the data to be sent, and still want the status of the relay to say the same so they both have priority. How do you account for that in the code?

A piece of the code is posted below. As you can see every 6 min or 360 seconds, I make a request and send data and every 20 seconds I make a request to read a file. So when the time alarm for the 6 min event goes off, there is a brief 5-10 state where the relay from the other event goes on or off.

```
#include "Wire.h"
#include "DS1307RTC.h"
#include "DHT.h"
#include "PID_v1.h"
#include "SPI.h"
#include "Time.h"
#include "TimeAlarms.h"
#include "WiFi.h"



#define SensorPin 2      
#define Offset 0            
#define DHTPIN 2
#define DHTTYPE DHT11
#define RELAY_ON 1
#define RELAY_OFF 0
#define Relay1  9  
#define Relay2  8
#define Relay3  6
#define Relay4  5
#define Relay5  4  
#define Relay6  3
#define Relay7  38
#define Relay8  39  

char server[] = "xx";  //IPAddress server(54,200,69,220); 
char ssid[] = "xx";     //SSID Home Network Name
char pass[] = "xx";  //Key or Network Password
int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;               
int analogChannel0 = 0; //Soil Moisture Sensor
int flag = 0;

unsigned long int avgValue;
WiFiClient client;



int xx = 300;
int zz = 20;
int ww = 360;
double Setpoint, Input, Output;
//onTime(18,20,25)
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);


void setup() {
     Setpoint = 7;
     dht.begin();
     Wire.begin();
     //myPID.SetSampleTime(30000);
     digitalWrite(Relay1, RELAY_ON);
     digitalWrite(Relay2, RELAY_ON);
     digitalWrite(Relay3, RELAY_ON);
     digitalWrite(Relay4, RELAY_ON);  
     digitalWrite(Relay5, RELAY_ON);
     digitalWrite(Relay6, RELAY_ON);
     digitalWrite(Relay7, RELAY_ON);
     digitalWrite(Relay8, RELAY_ON);

     pinMode(Relay1, OUTPUT);   
     pinMode(Relay2, OUTPUT);  
     pinMode(Relay3, OUTPUT);  
     pinMode(Relay4, OUTPUT);    
     pinMode(Relay5, OUTPUT);   
     pinMode(Relay6, OUTPUT);  
     pinMode(Relay7, OUTPUT); 
     pinMode(Relay8, OUTPUT); 

     Serial.begin(9600); 

     setSyncProvider(RTC.get);

      Alarm.timerRepeat(ww, SendData);   
      Alarm.timerRepeat(zz, ReadData);


     while ( status != WL_CONNECTED) { 
     status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);     
     }
     } //End of Void Setup

void loop() {     

            Alarm.delay(0);           
            } //End of Loop   

                void SendData(){            
                if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
                tmElements_t tm;

                int SoilMoisture = analogRead(analogChannel0);            

                client.print("GET xx");
                client.print("&SoilMoisture=");
                client.print(SoilMoisture);                             
                client.print("&Setpoint=");
                client.println(Setpoint);
                } 
                }           


                void ReadData() 
                {
                if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
                client.println("GET xx.txt HTTP/1.1");
                client.println("Host: xx");
                client.println("Connection: close");  //tell the server that we expect it to close the connection.  if we dont do this it should keep the connection open.
                client.println();
                }
                flag = 0;
                while (client.available()) {
                char c = client.read();
                Serial.write(c);
                if (c == '0'){
                flag = 0;
                }
                if (c == '1'){
                flag = 1;
                }              
                } 
                if (flag == 0) {
                digitalWrite(Relay3, LOW);
                }
                if (flag == 1) {
                digitalWrite(Relay3, HIGH);
                }
                }
```

Comment: Sounds like part of your code is briefly twiddling the relay when it shouldn't be - can you post some code showing where the relay is driven?

Comment: also check your ram usage, be sure to use volatile variabile if shared between interrupt, and remeber thet interrupt should be fast as they block other interrupt, breaking time-sensitive code